# Plot with low resolution curves

Tags: python, csv, matplotlib, antialiasing

My problem requirement is to redraw a graph with curves at low resolution. As shown below:

[image]

Is there a way to do it with matplotlib library or any image processing solution? Currently matplotlib is producing lines with very high smoothness as shown below:

[image]

Here is the drawing function I used:

```
with open('points.csv') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    for row in csv_reader:
        x = float(row[0])
        y = float(row[1])

        arr.append([x, y])

data = list(arr)

plt.plot(*zip(*data), color='black', linewidth=0.5, alpha=1.0)

plt.savefig("report.png")
```

Data example:

```
617,21.550045745097
617.25,21.4286797104602
617.5,21.3023081618079
617.75,21.1830623411815
618,21.0748879703542
```

`Note: Low resolution data curve only`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get close to this effect by changing the [`antialiased`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.lines.Line2D.html#matplotlib.lines.Line2D.set_antialiased) kwarg to `False` when calling [`plt.plot`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html) or [`ax.plot`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.plot.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.plot), which controls whether the line is smoothed or not. Consider the following:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(-5, 5)

y = x**3

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.plot(x, y, 'b-', lw=1, antialiased=True, label='antialiased=True')
ax.plot(x, y+10, 'k-', lw=1, antialiased=False, label='antialiased=False')

ax.legend()

plt.savefig('antialiased.png', dpi=100)
```

[image]

Comment: This is absolutely what I was looking for. Thank you